# How to hide the area lines in Polararea using vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I just have a polararea chart using vue-chartjs (http://vue-chartjs.org/#/). But I don't find the option to hide the 'area lines' (the circle ones) and the numbers (percentage) on them in this chart.

Find the example got from the demo examples:

[Screenshot for the example of one polararea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSdGO.png)

Could you help me with this configuration? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The [chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/polar.html#dataset-properties) should help you. You can set the border-colors in your dataset array.